# How to include plugins to Eclipse install using a script?

Tags: eclipse

If you try to use Eclipse for too many purposes you'll end-up with what I call Eclipzilla.

In order to overcome this you may want to have several Eclipse installation and use the one that has the proper plugins installed.

Now the question is how can I add these plugins to an Eclipse install from inside a script, instead of the manual process?

Answer (score 2):

The [p2 director application](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) enables you to install additional software to (or remove from) an Eclipse installation on the command line.

You can export a description of the software items (or a subset of them) in an Eclipse installation with *File > Export... > Install > Install Software Items to File* (available since Eclipse 3.7). The so exported XML document contains the ids of the corresponding installable units and the repositories that provide them, which you will both need as parameters for the p2 director application.

Note that there is also the counterpart *File > Import > Install > Install Software Items from File*, which can be used to recreate an Eclipse installation from an exported description of software items. Maybe this already fits your use case: to be able to recreate a particular Eclipse installation in a single step.

Comment: But how do you build the list of things to pass to the p2 director application?

Comment: You can export a list of installed software items (or a subset of them) from a running Eclipse installation via _File > Export... > Install > Installed Software Items to File_. This will get you an XML document that contains the ids of the installable units as well as the repositories that provide them. Use this to compile your list manually or write a script to feed it to the p2 director application. You will figure it out.

Comment: Thanks!  That "File > Export... > Install > Installed Software Items to File" piece is exactly what I've been wanting.  You might want to add it to your answer, since I think it's the right answer to the original question.  (Not everyone bothers to read comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can export and import repository lists in Eclipse Preferences under *Install/Update>Available Software Sites*.

You could use this to get part of what you want. Create export files by hand or script that contain the sites you want for a particular configuration. Then for a new installation, import one of those files. Next, in *Install New Software*, select *--All Available Sites--* and see your tailored list and standard Eclipse sites below. Pick the ones you want.

Comment: This is a pretty small part though.  You want all these sites, _plus_ all the plugins that you have installed, and then you want a tool that does the installing.